# Set a locale from code that will have global scope in android app

Tags: java, android

I have this code:

```
            Locale locale_en = new Locale("en"); 
            Locale.setDefault(locale_en);
            Configuration config_en = new Configuration();
            config_en.locale = locale_en;
            getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config_en, getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
```

It will change the locale and it works just fine. The problem is that when I change activity locales is set on default again for the new activity. Here is example code:

```
Button o_nas_bt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.o_nas_bt_id);      
o_nas_bt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent("com.investwroclaw.ONASACTIVITY"));
        }
    });
```

I would like to change locale for the whole app. Can somebody help me here?

Thax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. I have a solution that works in my particular case (meaning changing language on the home of the app). When I change language (that means change locale) I restart activity using Intent and this code:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(InvestWroclawActivity.this, InvestWroclawActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would actually consider using the phone's locale. It's actually pretty easy